# Convert php date into excel number string

Tags: php

I need to convert a PHP date into an Excel number; for example, `2019-06-01` in PHP is `43617` in Excel.

`$Result` must be the same as if I did `($June_date -  $Date_work)/365` in Excel.

The code I've tried so far is below, but it doesn't work.

```
$Date_work = ('2016-03-01');          
$June_date =  ('2019-06-01'); 

$Result = ($June_date - $Date_work); 
echo "$Result";
```

Comment: do you want difference in days ?

Comment: yes, please in days.

Comment: Check this : `<?php
      
$Date_work = strtotime('2016-03-01');          
$June_date =  strtotime('2019-06-01'); 
$Result = $June_date - $Date_work; 
echo (int)($Result/(60*60*24)).' Days';`

Comment: Yes, it solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: The result in excel is 3.25205479, not 3,25. If you need the difference in years, not every year has 365 Days!

Comment: Note: The number of seconds / (60 * 60 * 24) does not always give the number of days. Not all days have 24 hours. This applies to time-zones that have summer / winter time. DateTime works there correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2019-06-01';

$excelNumber = strtotime($date." UTC")/86400 + 25569;

echo $excelNumber;  //43617
```

or alternatively with the [DateTime extension dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt):

```
$excelNumber = dt::create($date,'UTC')->getMsTimeStamp();
```

For the difference in days you need not convert to excel-number

```
$Date_work = '2016-03-01';          
$June_date =  '2019-06-01'; 
$diffDays = date_create($Date_work)->diff(date_create($June_date))->days;
//1187
```